# Printing the difference between adjacent values in a column to a new column

Tags: awk

I have a file

```
A 1
A 2
A 4
A 6
```

I want to print the difference between adjacent values (below-above) in column 2 to a new column 3, to get this

```
A 1
A 2 1
A 4 2
A 6 2
```

I have discovered something [like this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476879/difference-between-number-in-the-same-column-using-awk), but failed to print it as a new column.

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1-p} {p=$1}' file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To modify the given code in question

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$3=$2-p} {p=$2} 1' file 
A 1
A 2 1
A 4 2
A 6 2
```

- Fields are indexed from `1`, so use `$2` for second column

  - `$0` contains entire input record
- After modifying, you need to print the record. Default action is printing contents of `$0` if condition is true. `1` is used idiomatically for such cases

Comment: Now I would like to modify the script so it prints the quotient of the division by the value 10 steps above. I tried awk 'NR>1{$3=$2/p} {p=$2} 10' file but failed. Maybe I misunderstood some parts of the script. How should I correct it?

Comment: @JohnnyTam I didn't get what are you trying... can you tell the three values you need? is this what you need? `awk 'NR>1{$3=int($2/p)} {p=$2} 1'`

Comment: Please go here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396195/print-values-which-are-at-least-2-times-larger-than-the-values-3-steps-above-and for a simplified illustration. :)

Answer (score -5):

UPDATE 1 : illustrating how drastic the difference for `++NF/—NF` between `mawk 1/2` and `gawk/nawk` :

- two ***completely** different set of results from the same jot of monotonically increasing integers

  -- silver lining is me accidentally discovering you can create these slanted patterns w/o actually doing any extra formatting

=

```
% jot 25 | 
  mawk '($(NF+=NR)=(++NF+(++NF)-NR)^$!NF)_' CONVFMT='%.310g' |
  gcut -c 1-40

1 6  
2  49  
3   512  
4    6561  
5     100000  
6      1771561  
7       35831808  
8        815730721  
9         20661046784  
10          576650390625  
11           17592186044416  
12            582622237229761  
13             20822964865671168  
14              799006685782884096  
15               32768000000000000000  
16                1430568690241985314816
17                 662499529194594317107
18                  32441509098952484034
19                   1674995299100251530
20                    909494701772928265
21                     51813187127544463
22                      3090315438263261
23                       192590438003727
24                        12518490081473
25                         8472886094430
```

=

```
% jot 25 | 
 gawk '($(NF+=NR)=(++NF+(++NF)-NR)^$!NF)_' CONVFMT='%.310g'|
 gcut -c 1-40

1   4
2    9
3     8
4      1
5       0
6        1
7         -128
8          6561
9           -262144
10            9765625
11             -362797056
12              13841287201
13               -549755813888
14                22876792454961
15                 -1000000000000000
16                  45949729863572160
17                   -221861110674043699
18                    112455406951957397
19                     -5976303958948914
20                      3325256730079651
21                       -19342813113834
22                        11745628765211
23                         -743477136140
24                          489876293096
25                           -3355443200
```

====================

```
mawk{1,2} 'NR<NF ? _=$NF :$++NF=-_+(_=$(NF-!__))'
 {n,g}awk 'NR<(__=NF) ?_=$__:ORS=" "(-_+(_=$__))RS'

     mawk 'NR<2?_=$2:$3=-_+(_=$2)'    # if you like hard-coding
                                      #  in the constants
```

=

```
A 1
A 2 1
A 4 2
A 6 2
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137479/discussion-on-answer-by-rare-kpop-manifesto-printing-the-difference-between-adja).

Comment: [You didn't like the suggested edit (from me)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/417216) and expecting us to like your answer as how it's currently written?

Comment: @αғsнιη : the suggested edit was incorrect - regardless of naming, it created completely unrelated variables with different values in the process.