# Print values which are at least 2 times larger than the values 3 steps above and below in the same column

Tags: awk

I have a list

```
2
2
2
3
2
2
2
4
2
2
2
```

I want to print the values which are at least 2 times larger than the values 3 steps above and below in the same column.

The output should be

```
4
```

How to do that? I have a similar question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395746/printing-the-difference-between-adjacent-values-in-a-column-to-a-new-column), just to better illustrate I write it here, thanks.

20171006 Update :
Sorry for oversimplifying my actual input file, it is actually a table instead of a list that I need to select in multiple columns (column 2, 3, 4 etc.) and print out column 1. How could I incorporate the column informations in such script?

```
A 2 2 2
B 2 2 2
C 2 2 2
D 3 3 3
E 2 2 2
F 2 2 2
G 2 2 2
H 4 4 4
I 2 2 2 
J 2 2 2 
K 2 2 2
```

And to get

```
H
```

Comment: all 3 values above/below or only 3rd value above/below?

Comment: 3rd above and 3rd below

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that in `awk`. You'd need to save the previous 6 lines to compare the 3rd last line with 6th last line and the current one. For that, the common trick is to use a ring buffer which is an array indexed by `NR%6` where `6` is the number of lines you want to keep.

```
awk '
  NR > 6 {
    x = saved[NR%6]; y = saved[(NR - 3) % 6]; z = $0
    if (y >= 2*x && y >= 2*z) print y
  }
  {saved[NR % 6] = $0}'  < file
```

For your edit: save the key and value to compare:

```
awk -v key=1 -v value=2 '
  NR > 6 {
    x = saved_value[NR%6]; y = saved_value[(NR - 3) % 6]; z = $value
    if (y >= 2*x && y >= 2*z) print saved_key[(NR - 3) % 6]
  }
  {saved_key[NR % 6] = $key; saved_value[NR % 6] = $value}'  < file
```

where `key` is the index of column you want to print and `value` the column with the values you want to compare.

Or based on whatever metric you'd like based on those columns 2, 3, 4 like the average:

```
awk '
  {metric = ($2 + $3 + $4) / 3}
  NR > 6 {
    x = saved_metric[NR%6]; y = saved_metric[(NR - 3) % 6]; z = $metric
    if (y >= 2*x && y >= 2*z) print saved_key[(NR - 3) % 6]
  }
  {saved_key[NR % 6] = $key; saved_metric[NR % 6] = $metric}'  < file
```

Comment: Sorry for oversimplifying my actual input file, it is actually a table instead of a list that I need to select in multiple columns (column 2, 3, 4 etc.) and print out column 1. How could I incorporate the column informations in such script?

Comment: @JohnnyTam, see edit.

Comment: After I changed the name of file to my input table name in the second script, the error "No such file or directory" while running it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @JohnnyTam, sorry there was a typo in the code (missing -v in front of value=2). Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!!!
How about if I want to modify it so it just considers the value above OR below (i.e. not AND), I just change the && to || in this part (y >= 2*x && y >= 2*z)? I tried but failed, values larger than the value above OR below were not printed out. Is it I have to modify something more? Thank you!

Comment: I discovered something more, to make it more clear : 
I have tested the script if "OR" (i.e. changing && to || only) works by two ways :
1) by placing the 4 (as in the illustration above) near the end (e.g. 2nd last) of the list, that means the "3rd number below" does not exist.
2) by keeping the 3rd value above the same but changing the 3rd value below as 3 (i.e. less than two fold smaller than 4).

Comment: For the result of 1), && and || are the same, both output the H.
For the result of 2), && and || are not the same. && no output, II output H.

Actually, in short, the question boils down to: how would the script consider if there is one condition impossible (i.e. 3rd value below does not exist), will it be TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: @Johnny, not sure what you mean. Here, for each input record we're looking at the record from 3 iterations in the past (`y = saved[(NR-3)%6]`) and we're not doing until we've reached the 7th input record (`NR > 6`), so in effect the first and last 3 lines are not considered and will never be output.

Comment: It answered my question, thank you! Since the situation is getting complicated, I have another modification, I am glad if you could take a look here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396647/print-values-which-are-at-least-2-times-larger-than-the-values-3-steps-above-and

Answer (score 5):

Without reading the entire file in memory:

```
paste <(tail -n+4 file.txt | head -n-3) <(head -n-6 file.txt) <(tail -n+7 file.txt) |
    awk '$1 >= 2*$2 && $1 >= 2*$3 {print $1}'
```

This needs a shell that can handle `<(...)` constructs (f.i. AT&T `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh`) and a `head` implementation that supports negative offsets.

**Explanation:** the `paste` command above puts on the same line the current value, the value 3 steps above, and the value 3 steps below; the `awk` command checks the 2 times larger conditions.

Comment: Error "Missing name for redirect." appeared, is it related to the problem of shell which cannot handle <(...) constructs (f.i. AT&T ksh, bash or zsh) and head?

Comment: @JohnnyTam Yes, you need a (slightly) smarter shell.

Answer (score 2):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk 'function mean(sum){ 
          m=sum/3; return (int(m) == m)? m: int(m)+1 
     }
     { a[NR]=$0 }
     END{ 
         for(i=4;i<=NR-3;i++) 
             if (a[i]>=mean(a[i-3]+a[i-2]+a[i-1])*2 &&
                a[i]>=mean(a[i+3]+a[i+2]+a[i+1])*2) 
             print a[i] 
     }' file
```

---

- `a[NR]=$0` - collecting all values into array `a` indexed with record numbers `NR`

---

The output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 2):

If [you only need compare with 3<sup>rd</sup> value above/below only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396195/print-values-which-are-at-least-2-times-larger-than-the-values-3-steps-above-and#comment707064_396195), then that's easier with the below `awk` command.

```
awk -vRS='' '{for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>=$(i-3)*2 && $i>=$(i+3)*2 ) print $i}' infile
```

Or in short.

```
awk -vRS='' '{for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>=$(i%3)*2) print $i}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

So you would have to keep a sliding window of 3 + 1 + 3 input lines to be able to do this.

```
awk -vn=3 -va=2 'BEGIN { N=2*n+1 } { t=(NR-n)%N; m=NR%N; b=(NR+n)%N; w[b]=$0 } NR >= N && w[m] >= a*w[t] && w[m] >= a*w[b] { print w[m] }' file
```

This would print all values fulfill the criteria, with the added bonus that you can easily modify the distance by tweaking the variable `n` on the command line (change `-vn=3`) and the weight by changing `a` (change `-va=2`).

The code stores the last N values where N is 2*n + 1 in a cyclic buffer `w`.  If the middle value, `w[m]`, is bigger than `a` times the first value in the buffer, `w[t]` (`t` for "top"), and `a` times bigger than the last value in the buffer, `w[b]` (`b` for "bottom"), then it is printed.

---

The `awk` script unravelled:

```
BEGIN   { N = 2*n + 1 }

        {
            t = (NR - n)%N
            m = NR%N
            b = (NR + n)%N
            w[b] = $0
        }

NR >= N && w[m] >= a*w[t] && w[m] >= a*w[b] { print w[m] }
```