# Print values which are at least 2 times larger than the values 3 steps above and below in the same column (cont. 1)

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a table

```
A 1
A 1
A 1
A 1
A 1
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 1
B 1
B 2
B 1
B 1
B 1
```

I want to print column 1 of lines with values of column 2 at least 2 times larger than the 3rd step above AND 3rd step below in the same column. **However, only consider the lines with the same name in column 1.**

Therefore, output should be

```
B
```

I want to modify upon this script which is written by Stéphane Chazelas, to meet the additional requirement in bold above.

```
awk -v key=1 -v value=2 '
  NR > 6 {
    x = saved_value[NR%6]; y = saved_value[(NR - 3) % 6]; z = $value
    if (y >= 2*x && y >= 2*z) print saved_key[(NR - 3) % 6]
  }
  {saved_key[NR % 6] = $key; saved_value[NR % 6] = $value}'  < file
```

(It is actually a post continued from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396195/print-values-which-are-at-least-2-times-larger-than-the-values-3-steps-above-and#comment707064_396195). Since there is a more complicated situation, I want to illustrate better it here.)

.
.
.

20171010 update :

I am now modifying the script written by Stéphane Chazelas but now I am selecting the lines with values that are **at least 2 times smaller than the 3rd value above and 3rd value below**. Previously I simplified the example and so I could understand and modify the script by myself to `v2 <= v1/2 && v2 <= v3/2`, but again, failed... To make the matter more direct, I am now providing the real file as follows, where the values in the 2nd column are useless and the **values in the 3rd columns are to be compared** :

```
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   1   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   2   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   3   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   4   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   5   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   6   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   7   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   8   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   9   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   10  1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    1   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    2   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    3   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    4   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    5   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    6   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    7   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    8   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    9   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    10  2
```

If whole lines are printed, expected output is :

```
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    4   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    5   1
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    6   1
```

This is my failed modification :

```
awk -v key=1 -v value=3 '
  NR > 6 {
    k1 = saved_key[NR%6];   k2 = saved_key[(NR - 3) % 6];   k3 = $key
    v1 = saved_value[NR%6]; v2 = saved_value[(NR - 3) % 6]; v3 = $value
    if (k1 == k2 && k2 == k3 && v2 <= v1/2 && v2 <= v3/2) print $0
  }
  {saved_key[NR % 6] = $key; saved_value[NR % 6] = $value}' < test
```

How could I correct it?

.
.
.

20171011 update :

How could I add an additional key so I could **compare the values in column 3 with 3rd values above and below in column 4 (i.e. a different column)**? Please refer to 20171011 update. Thanks again!

```
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   1   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   2   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   3   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   4   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   5   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   6   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   7   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   8   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   9   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668   10  1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    1   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    2   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    3   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    4   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    5   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    6   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    7   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    8   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    9   0   2
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    10  0   2
```

If whole lines are printed, expected output is :

```
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    4   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    5   1   0
K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686    6   1   0
```

It is my trial :

```
awk -v key1=1 -v key2=2 -v value1=3 -v value2=4 '
    {
    k1 = saved_key1[NR%6];   k2 = saved_key1[(NR - 3) % 6];   k3 = $key1
    k4 = saved_key2[NR%6];   k5 = saved_key2[(NR - 3) % 6];   k6 = $key2
    v1 = saved_value1[NR%6]; v2 = saved_value1[(NR - 3) % 6]; v3 = $value1
    v4 = saved_value2[NR%6]; v5 = saved_value2[(NR - 3) % 6]; v6 = $value2
    if (k1 == k2 && k2 == k3 && v2 <= v4/2 && v2 <= v6/2) print saved_record[(NR-3)%6]
  }
  {saved_key1[NR % 6] = $key1; saved_value1[NR % 6] = $value1}' < file
```

Comment: Re: your latest edit. You're printing `$0`, `$0` is the current record, so the record for the 3rd line below the one you're checking. So you'd need to print `k2`, or also save the full record instead of just key and value and `print saved_record[(NR-3)%6]` if you want the whole record.

Comment: How could I add an additional key so I could **compare the values in column 3 with 3rd values above and below in column 4 (i.e. a different column)**? Please refer to 20171011 update. Thanks again!

Comment: you should be able to figure that out.

Comment: I tried to modify the script but failed... as it is written above.

Comment: You're never storing anything in the saved_key2, saved_value2, saved_record. You could instead save the whole record and re-split upon checking as shown in the second example in my answer.

Comment: I see. Actually, the second example worked according to the requirement already though the script is even more difficult for me to understand compared with the first version, so I modified the first version... but after many trials still failed to compare with a different column.

Comment: See if the latest edit to my answer makes it any clearer. You may want to take a awk introduction tutorial to learn about its basic principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it would be:

```
awk -v key=1 -v value=2 '
  NR > 6 { # for 7th record and over only
    k1 = saved_key[NR%6];   k2 = saved_key[(NR - 3) % 6];   k3 = $key
    v1 = saved_value[NR%6]; v2 = saved_value[(NR - 3) % 6]; v3 = $value
    if (k1 == k2 && k2 == k3 && v2 >= 2*v1 && v2 >= 2*v3) print k2
  }
  # for every record, save key and value in ring buffers:
  {saved_key[NR % 6] = $key; saved_value[NR % 6] = $value}'
```

Note that the `k1 == k2` and `k2 == k3` comparisons will be numerical if the values look like numbers (so `00` will be considered the same as `0`) and textual otherwise. Change to `k1 "" == k2` to force a textual comparison.

Or save the whole records and re-split when checking. Like for your *20171010 update*:

```
awk -v key=1 -v value=3 '
  NR > 6 {
    # "above" is an array with the fields of 6th last record
    split(saved_record[NR%6], above)
    # "text" is the 3rd last record and the one we will be looking at
    text = saved_record[(NR - 3) % 6]
    # "text" fields split into the "here" array.
    split(text, here)
    # $0 contains the current record (the one 3 lines below "here")
    # and $1, $2, $3... the fields of that record.
    if (above[key] == here[key] && here[key] == $key && \
        here[value] <= above[value] / 2 && here[value] <= $value / 2)
      print text
  }
  {saved_record[NR % 6] = $0}'
```

Comment: I met some problems when I tried to modify the script, would you mind taking a look of an update down below… Thank you very much!

Comment: I move the comment to here : "Change the value=2 to value=3 if you want to consider the value in the 3rd column instead of second."

Yes, I have changed value = 3, and also this v2 <= v1/2 && v2 <= v3/2, but failed. I am curious if I should change something more.

Comment: Please refer to the original post to see my version of modification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively short GNU **`datamash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
datamash -W -g1 count 2 collapse 2 <file | awk '$2==7{ split($3,a,","); k=a[4]; 
             delete a[4]; if(k>=a[7]*2) print $1 }'
```

Comment: The above solution is too hard for me to fix... I tried datamash and the output seems to be more easily understood. If it is possible, would you mind taking a look at the 20171011 update, that how about comparing the values of a different column? How could I modify the command using datamash? Thank you so much.